# Return the result while the process is running

Tags: c#, batch-file, process

I have a program which start a batch process. This batch file is a consuming process and I want to return the result while the process is running. I try to use await and async but nothing works.

```
            result = String.Empty;
            ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startinfo.FileName = RunText;
            startinfo.Arguments = "cmd";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startinfo;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
          
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.Start();
            
           
            while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                result = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();//I want to return the result  
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                    
            }
```

-This is my batch program. The output is 1 if there is a connection with another PC.

```
@echo off
:begin
for /F "tokens=*" %%L in ('netstat -n ^| find ":3389" ^| find "ESTABLISHED" /c') do (set "VAR=%%L")
echo %VAR%
goto begin
```

I am beginner with this topics(processes and multi-threading). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Processes and threads are two very different things. Multithreading doesn't involve multiple processes. You can't use thread functions, much less Task functions to work with processes

Comment: What does that process do anyway? Does it write anything to the console? If not, there won't be anything to read

Comment: The parenthesized command within the `for` loop will run, and output its results to the `do` portion once completed. It does not pass each line of output dynamically to the `do` portion, which is what I assume you were expecting, and is therefore not going to be appropriate for your task.

Comment: The result of the batch file is 1 or 0 in an endless loop. I want to take this result every 1 sec and return this result

Answer (score 0):

Use handlers to achieve this:

```
public static void MyHandler(object process, DataReceivedEventArgs dataReceived)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataReceived.Data))
    {
        // do something you want here, for an example
        Console.WriteLine(dataReceived.Data);
    }
}
```

And in `main` method:

```
//...
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(MyHandler);
process.Start();
```